# strConv treats parenthesis as the first letter

Tags: vba, excel

strConv in the code below returns 
(hello World) 
rather than the desired 
(Hello World)
because it treats the first parenthesis as the first letter of the word "HELLO".
Could anyone advise how to overcome this problem please ?

```
 Dim MyString
    Dim MyCaseString
        MyString = "(HELLO WORLD)"
        MyCaseString = strConv(MyString, 3)
    MsgBox MyCaseString
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Mid() to slice off the leading "(" -- which can be added back in:

```
Sub test()
    Dim MyString
    Dim MyCaseString
    MyString = "(HELLO WORLD)"
    MyCaseString = "(" & StrConv(Mid(MyString, 2), 3)
    MsgBox MyCaseString
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much John Coleman. Works perfectly. I am obliged to you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally do this with a regular expression (you'll need a reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5):

```
Dim regex As New RegExp
Dim matches As MatchCollection
Dim word As Match

Dim sample As String
sample = "(HELLO WORLD)"

With regex
    .Pattern = "\w+"
    .Global = True
    Set matches = .Execute(sample)
End With

For Each word In matches
    sample = Replace$(sample, word, StrConv(word, vbProperCase))
Next word

Debug.Print sample
```

Comment: Thank you Comintern. That looks very interesting indeed. I'll try and learn from that tomorrow. Very much obliged to you.

Answer (score 0):

Such as John Coleman,use `Replace` function can do the same thing.

1. Method 1-->this will replace left parenthesis
2. Method 2-->this will replace left/right parenthesis

Method 1:

```
Sub Test1()

    Dim MyString
    Dim MyCaseString

    MyString = "(HELLO WORLD)"
    MyCaseString = "(" & StrConv(Replace(MyString, "(", ""), 3)

    MsgBox MyCaseString
End Sub
```

Method 2:

```
Sub Test2()

    Dim MyString
    Dim MyCaseString

    MyString = "(HELLO WORLD)"

    mystr = Replace(Replace(MyString, "(", ""), ")", "")
    MyCaseString = "(" & StrConv(mystr, vbProperCase) & ")"

    MsgBox MyCaseString
End Sub
```